# How do you return the result from the google geocoding API on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I'm trying to create a function that uses the google geocoding API for node.js to create a variable called geodata and return it. For some reason the value temp will have the result I want but if i use i outside of the function, the value of temp is undefined.

```
var temp;
function getInfo(inAddress){
  googleMapsClient.geocode({
    address: inAddress,
    region: 'MY'
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (!err) {
      details = response.json.results;
      var geodata = {
        "status": response.json.status,
        "formattedAddress": details[0].formatted_address,
        "latitude": details[0].geometry.location.lat,
        "longitude": details[0].geometry.location.lng,
        "type": details[0].geometry.location_type,
      };
      for(i=0; details[0].address_components.length; i++){
        if(details[0].address_components[i].types == "postal_code"){
          geodata.postCode = details[0].address_components[i].long_name;
        }
        temp = geodata
        console.log(temp); 
      }
    }
  });
}

getInfo('Nadayu28');
```

Comment: asynchronous code is asynchronous

Comment: can I use a promise? would that help? I'm trying to learn how to use them but I wanna know if I'm just wasting my time

Comment: promises won't help has they are asynchronous too, so if asynchronous code is not something you know how to work with, Promises wont help. However, the next evolution of them, async/await, can make asynchronous code "look" synchronous, but you still need to know how to work with asynchronism to use them properly ... you're not wasting your time, just stop looking for a magic bullet to make asynchronous tasks work synchronously - it's impossible

Comment: ok can you please just point me in the right direction. A key word I should search for or a link to help. what would you do

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be asynchronous, and you can make it using promises or async/await, like this:

```
const Promise=require('bluebird');

async function getInfo(inAddress){
  return Promise.promisify(googleMapsClient.geocode)({
    address: inAddress,
    region: 'MY'
  }).then((response)=> {
      details = response.json.results;
      var geodata = {
        "status": response.json.status,
        "formattedAddress": details[0].formatted_address,
        "latitude": details[0].geometry.location.lat,
        "longitude": details[0].geometry.location.lng,
        "type": details[0].geometry.location_type,
      };
      for(i=0; details[0].address_components.length; i++){
        if(details[0].address_components[i].types == "postal_code"){
          geodata.postCode = details[0].address_components[i].long_name;
        }
        return geodata;
      }
    }
  });
}

const data = await getInfo('Nadayu28');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple callback to make it work. I have also fixed few bugs. Here is the working version of your code.

```
var googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
    key: 'Your Key'
});

function getInfo(inAddress, callback) {
    googleMapsClient.geocode({
        address: inAddress,
        region: 'MY'
    }, function(err, response) {
        if (!err) {
            details = response.json.results;
            var geodata = {
                "status": response.json.status,
                "formattedAddress": details[0].formatted_address,
                "latitude": details[0].geometry.location.lat,
                "longitude": details[0].geometry.location.lng,
                "type": details[0].geometry.location_type,
            };
            for (i = 0; i < details[0].address_components.length; i++) {
                if (details[0].address_components[i].types.indexOf("postal_code") !== -1) {
                    geodata.postCode = details[0].address_components[i].long_name;
                }
            }

            callback(null, geodata);
        } else {
            callback(err, null);
        }
    });
}

getInfo('Nadayu28', function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```